# Is this a good enough way to "hide" the db credentials?

Tags: php, database

Just looking for some tips if this is good enough or if i should do anything different to "hide" my database credentials. Been searching for a long time. I have found alot of ways to do this and feel everyone does it a different way. So wondering if this is good enough. Thank you.

Right now I'm storing a config.ini file with my database credentials **outside of the public directory**. 
Then inside the public directory I got a folder name db_includes. This is where i have my db connection php file. This is the code for the database connection.

```
$config = parse_ini_file('../../private/config.ini');
$db = new \PDO('mysql:dbname='.$config['DB_NAME'].';host='.$config['DB_SERVER'].';charset=utf8mb4', ''.$config['DB_USERNAME'].'', ''.$config['DB_PWD'].'');
```

Also inside the db_includes folder i got a .htaccess file that has "deny from all" so its not possible to get to that db_includes folder or the database connection file.

Is this good or should i also move the database connection file outside of the public directory and just call it when i need it?

Comment: Keeping it outside of the docroot is best practice, and the `.htaccess` access control is unnecessary. Even if someone requested the file in `db_includes` it wouldn't output anything unless you did something foolish like `var_dump($config);` which you could do in _any_ file, and even if your httpd config broke and it served the bare PHP source there's _still_ no sensitive data in that file.

Comment: @Sammitch Alright i understand. Very new to this whole make a secure connection and keep the credentials safe part of PHP. Thank you for the good information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways of doing it. First, I recommend using a PHP file to store the credentials, this way if your htaccess fails, the php file will be parsed anyway and your credentials won't appear:

config.php:

```
<?php

return [
    "DB_NAME" => "database",
    "DB_USER" => "user"
    // ...
];
```

Wherever you need:

```
$config = require "path/to/config.php";
$db = new \PDO('mysql:dbname='.$config['DB_NAME'].';host='.$config['DB_SERVER'].';charset=utf8mb4', ''.$config['DB_USERNAME'].'', ''.$config['DB_PWD'].'');
```

If possible, keep it outside your public folder as it is a good way to make it safe.

Remember that if your database and server is well configured and safe enough you don't need to worry about database credentials.

Comment: Alright thank you for that. Do you recommend that i call the db connection file whenever i need it or include the db connection code in each file that needs it? The first one right?

Comment: Create a code capable of having the database connection as a singleton, allowing to reuse the connection by your entire code. I don't know your level of expertise in programming and php, but ai really suggest you studying about autoloader (and composer autoloader), object oriented programming and then seek for some design patterns. Creating your own code is great for learning, but you will have a lot work to make it great. Using some framework may save you some time and also teach you cool things. Search for Laravel!